# How to resolve the error, "module umap has no attribute UMAP".. I tried installing & reinstalling umap but didn't work to me

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

[image]

```
AttributeError: module 'umap' has no attribute 'UMAP'
```

I tried installing & reinstalling different libraries of umap and umap learn but didn't work any..

Comment: It would help others if you could specify your OS platform, the library's version, python's version, and the commands you ran that led up to this error.

Comment: win10, python 3.7.1 & see the image I attached

Comment: Don’t call your source umap.py

Comment: I get the same error ImportError: cannot import name 'UMAP'

Comment: In case it helps anyone else, for me it started working after installing the modules with `python -m pip install umap` instead of `pip install umap` due to path/venv issues.

Answer (score 90):

To use `UMAP` you need to install `umap-learn` not `umap`.
So, in case you installed `umap` run the following commands to uninstall umap and install upam-learn instead:

```
pip uninstall umap
pip install umap-learn
```

And then in your python code make sure you are importing the module using:

```
import umap.umap_ as umap
```

Instead of

```
import umap
```

Comment: I am getting AttributeError: module 'umap.umap_' has no attribute 'plot' any solution ?

Comment: Why was the namespace changed like this? The docs are incorrect for `umap-learn` due to this change...

Comment: Kaustuv
This worked for me:
import umap.umap_ as umap
import umap.plot as umap_plot
then 
umap.UMAP(...)
umap_plot.points(...)

Answer (score 16):

If you still facing the issue try this.

```
import umap.umap_ as umap
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I don't understand why? Shouldn't umap.umap_.UMAP()... work as well?

Answer (score 10):

I have got the same issue and found two solutions:

1 - Solving on your machine by updating the library via git

```
git clone https://github.com/lmcinnes/umap
cd umap
pip install --user -r requirements.txt
python setup.py install --user
```

[Source](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/4357/runumap-in-seurat-not-working-module-umap-has-no-attribute-umap/4402#4402)

2 - Solving on Colab by forcing the installation of a version of umap

```
!pip install 'umap-learn==0.3.10'
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem as well, and it was all my fault.

I named the python file I was writing my code as umap.py.

I changed the name to umap_application.py and the problem was resolved. So, check if you named any of your files as umap.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have umap installed instead of umap-learn. In unix systems you can check that with pip freeze | grep umap

Answer (score 2):

If you use conda to create separate environments (which I highly recommend), you can install `umap-learn` there and it should work fine:

- Assuming you have a new conda environment, `env1`, with pip and python, in your terminal type `conda activate env1`.
- Then, `pip install umap-learn`
- In Spyder, switch your kernel to `env1`.

Should be able to call `import umap` and `reducer = umap.UMAP()` just fine now.

Comment: It worked. The issue for me is how I was importing and calling it. I've tried `import umap` and `import umap.umap_ as umap` but none worked. Then I realized I was calling it something as like `reducer = UMAP()` and it should be  `reducer = umap.UMAP()` . Kind of obvious but I was struggling a bit until find out. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to run it at [google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/). When it hint umap is undifind , run

```
!pip uninstall umap
!pip install umap-learn -i https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/pypi/web/simple
```

then `import umap` and `umap.UMAP` can be used.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem and revolved it by importing umap as something other than "umap"

```
import umap as mp
reducer = mp.UMAP()
```