# ImportError: cannot import name 'UMAP' from 'umap' (c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\umap\__init__.py)

Tags: python-3.x

I have already followed the tips in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57242208/how-to-resolve-the-error-module-umap-has-no-attribute-umap-i-tried-installi/57569442).

The problem is that I get the error from running this line of code:

`from bertopic import BERTopic`

Any tips for how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue just trying to import umap (`from umap import UMAP`).

If you have `umap` installed (`pip3 list | grep umap`), first uninstall it (`pip3 uninstall umap`) then reinstall using `pip3 install umap-learn`.

Note that at the time of this writing, the umap-learn module does not yet have a wheel built for the new Macs with the M1 chip, and cannot be used without some serious workarounds.

Credit for this fix goes to: https://www.kaitaiblog.com.tw/?p=254

Answer (score 3):

In Windows OS, if you have installed miniconda then
at location "C:\ProgramData\miniconda3\envs\customer-call\Lib\site-packages\umap", you will find all files related to umap module.

There is no file by the name UMAP, although its a class defined in umap_.py file

So wherever in BERTopic or related other modules/files `from umap import UMAP` appears,  replace it with `from umap import umap_ as UMAP`

To use the UMAP class you should use it like `UMAP.UMAP(constructor params)`

This solved the issue for me.