# Errors when running umap.UMAP(), no module named and module has no attribute

Tags: python

I am currently having trouble with using the UMAP library to get my dataset to a 2d dataset.

I am currently working on a virtual environment which has the version 0.5.4 of the `umap-library` package installed.

When running a simple code like this one found in the [documentation](https://umap-learn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic_usage.html#penguin-data):

```
import umap

def umap2d3d(data,dims):
  reducer = umap.UMAP(n_components=dims)
  embedding = reducer.fit_transform(data)
```

I get the error `AttributeError: module 'umap' has no attribute 'UMAP'`.

I have also followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57242208/how-to-resolve-the-error-module-umap-has-no-attribute-umap-i-tried-installi)'s advice and tried

```
import umap as mp
def umap2d3d(data,dims):
  reducer = mp.UMAP(n_components=dims)
  embedding = reducer.fit_transform(data)
```

but I get the same error.

Finally, I tried another solution from the same question and did the following:

```
import umap.umap_ as umap
def umap2d3d(data,dims):
  reducer = umap.UMAP(n_components=dims)
  embedding = reducer.fit_transform(data)
```

This gave me a different result, but it's still an error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'umap.umap_'`.

Can someone please help me figure out a way around this? I am currently using MacOS, VS Code and Python 3.9